# 'Future<GeoFirePoint>' is not a subtype of type 'GeoFirePoint' in type cast

Tags: flutter, types, future

I have a function that gets coordinates latitude and longitude:

```
Future <GeoFirePoint> getCenter() async  {

var center = await geolocatorService.getInitialLocation()

       .then  (  (position)  {

          return GeoFirePoint( position.latitude, position.longitude);

   }, onError: throw Exception('Intentional exception')
       );}
```

When I try to assign it:

```
late GeoFirePoint center =  getCenter() as GeoFirePoint;
```

I get the above error. Tried peppering the function with async /awaits, but I seem to be missing something.  More problems arise if I remove the cast.

Comment: Maybe `late GeoFirePoint center =  await getCenter() as GeoFirePoint;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your `getCenter()` function returns a `Future` of `GeoFirePoint`.

```
late GeoFirePoint center;

Future <GeoFirePoint> getCenter() async  {
 final position = await geolocatorService.getInitialLocation();
 center = GeoFirePoint(position.latitude, position.longitude);
}
```

This assigns the correct value to your variable. To catch exceptions you can wrap the line containing the `await` keyword in a `try/catch` block.

Comment: it worked, I just don't understand why Future of the same type is incompatible with the assigned type.  Still new to flutter. What I thought was that once the async function finishes the return type is no longer future but just a regular type. @stefan

Comment: also, is there any problem if use return center = GeoFirePoint(... ) ? that's the only way to avoid a potential non-null body error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning `getCenter()` value to variable `center` use `FutureBuilder` to get value from `getCenter()` like this

```
FutureBuilder<GeoFirePoint>(
      future: getCenter(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('Loading...');
        }
        return Text('${snapshot.data}'); /// snapshot.data is the type of GeoFirePoint
      },
    );
```

Comment: thanks! but for this particular case, its just to set up some particular initial values and not really for UI. I'm adapting GeoFlutterFire's example and It's way over my head!  haha